# Плавное смешивание и замена картинок в галерее JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, инспекция-кода

У меня есть гелерея с картинками, над ней несколько ссылок при клике на которых меняется содержание[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня это реализовано при помощи data-*, но при такой реализации я не могу сделать требуемые эффекты плавного исчезновения ненужных и появления нужных слайдов слайдов.
Задача: При клике на ссылку не актуальные слайды из прошлой ссылки плавно изчезают, остаются только актуальные, плюс они встают, тоже плавно, на место исчезнувших слайдов.

Я очень топорно реализовал это, оно работает, но выглядит ужасно. Подскажите как я могу оптимизировать код. Возможно есть какое то решение от jQuery.

```
/**================================================================================*/
/**-----------------------------PORTFOLIO GALLERY----------------------------------*/
/**================================================================================*/
const portfolioItem = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio-item')
const portfolioAll = document.getElementById("portfolio-all");
const portfolioLayout = document.getElementById("portfolio-layout");
const portfolioApps = document.getElementById("portfolio-apps");
const pointer = document.getElementsByClassName('pointer')
const portfolioFilter = document.getElementById('filter')

portfolioFilter.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if(event.target === portfolioApps) {
            portfolioItem[1].style.opacity = '0';
            portfolioItem[1].style.transform = 'scale(0)';
            portfolioItem[1].style.transition = '.5s';

            portfolioItem[2].style.opacity = '0';
            portfolioItem[2].style.transform = 'scale(0)';
            portfolioItem[2].style.transition = '.5s';

            portfolioItem[3].style.opacity = '0';
            portfolioItem[3].style.transform = 'scale(0)';
            portfolioItem[3].style.transition = '.5s';


            portfolioItem[5].style.opacity = '0';
            portfolioItem[5].style.transform = 'scale(0)';
            portfolioItem[5].style.transition = '.5s';


            portfolioItem[0].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[0].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[0].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[0].style.transition = '.5s';

            portfolioItem[4].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[4].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[4].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[4].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[4].style.top = '0';

        }else if(event.target === portfolioLayout) {
            portfolioItem[0].style.opacity = '0';
            portfolioItem[0].style.transform = 'scale(0)';
            portfolioItem[0].style.transition = '.5s';

            portfolioItem[4].style.opacity = '0';
            portfolioItem[4].style.transform = 'scale(0)';
            portfolioItem[4].style.transition = '.5s';


            portfolioItem[1].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[1].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[1].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[1].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[1].style.top = '0';
            portfolioItem[1].style.left = '0';

            portfolioItem[2].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[2].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[2].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[2].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[2].style.top = '0';
            portfolioItem[2].style.left = '33.3319%';

            portfolioItem[3].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[3].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[3].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[3].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[3].style.top = '0';
            portfolioItem[3].style.left = '66.6638%';

            portfolioItem[5].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[5].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[5].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[5].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[5].style.top = '28%';
            portfolioItem[5].style.left = '0';

        }else if(event.target === portfolioAll) {
            portfolioItem[0].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[0].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[0].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[0].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[0].style.top = '0';
            portfolioItem[0].style.left = '0';

            portfolioItem[1].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[1].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[1].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[1].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[1].style.top = '0';
            portfolioItem[1].style.left = '33.3319%';

            portfolioItem[2].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[2].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[2].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[2].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[2].style.top = '0';
            portfolioItem[2].style.left = '66.3338%';

            portfolioItem[3].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[3].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[3].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[3].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[3].style.top = '51%';
            portfolioItem[3].style.left = '0';

            portfolioItem[4].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[4].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[4].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[4].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[4].style.top = '27%';
            portfolioItem[4].style.left = '33.3319%';

            portfolioItem[5].style.display = 'block';
            portfolioItem[5].style.opacity = '1';
            portfolioItem[5].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            portfolioItem[5].style.transition = '.5s';
            portfolioItem[5].style.top = '58%';
            portfolioItem[5].style.left = '66.3338%';
        }
})
```

Прошу говной не кидаться, я только учусь.

Comment: Самое простое: в CSS прописать все необходимые свойства...например для `.my-class-1`, `my-class-2` и т.д.,  а потом в JS просто сделать `addClass` или `removeClass` для нужного элемента (на чистом js будет типа `element.classList.add` и `element.classList.remove`)

Comment: что именно не так с приведенным кодом? Он не работает? Он работает не так как ты хочешь? Он работает - но ты хочешь что-то поменять - что именно?

Comment: Он работает, но хотелось бы как то лаконичнее что ли его организовать.

Comment: зачем прописывать каждый раз transition? его же можно один раз указать в css для нужных элементов

Comment: Да, действительно, как и скейл

Comment: scale у тебя меняется в зависимости от выбранного пункта

Comment: @Grundy ну там есть паттерн на одинаковость, так что всё равн можно распихать всё по классам CSS

Comment: Да, странно , что я сам к этому не пришел. Попробую на классах сделать. Благодарю)

Comment: @DmitriiChizhov. фактически тебе два класса нужно - один который показывает - второй - скрывает. это уже уменьшит код, далее если посмотришь - ты всегда меняешь все элементы, значит эти блоки можно заменить циклом по всем элементам.